# Formula Firewall issue preventing passing parameters from Excell worksheet to SQL stored procedure

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm passing several parameters stored in cells in an Excel worksheet to a SQL USP, building the SQL in the code for the source:

`= Sql.Database("SERVERNAME.local", "live", [Query=" EXECUTE usp_queryname '"& #"par_job_no" &"', '"& #"par_from" &"', '"& #"par_to" &"'" ])`

I have set the Current Workbook privacy options in PQ to "Ignore the Privacy Levels ..." but for anyone whose Global privacy level is set to "Always combine data according to your Privacy Level settings for each source" the query gives this error:

"Formula.Firewall: Query 'job_history_upload' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination."

Is there some way of creating the SQL for the data source without triggering the firewall?

Comment: Link-only comment: https://excelguru.ca/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/ --> it helped me to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ike. I had seen this article and tried the solution it proposes, but the "staging query" itself then triggers the Formula.Firewall message even if I divide the queries that pull the parameters from the worksheet into two parts as shown. Having said that, there are a number of other suggestions in the comments to the article that sound like they may be promising that I haven't had time to look at yet so I'm going to revisit it as soon as I can.